# The best range to measure the differences between glass, can and plastic

Tags: visible-light, absorption

First of all,
 i'm **Computer science student**, so maybe the question is simple for this forum
       so  **i'm apologize** and hope that i will found help here

I working on recycle bin which automatically throws item to specific bin. my problem is to detect the type of product and i thought to do that by absorption.

**My question** is what is the best way to get differences between glass , cans and plastic in terms of absorption

Answer (score 0):

If your containers are painted and/or opaque, transmission will be useless. Reflection could help, but here again, unless you have specific constraints on the containers, I think that this would not work very well. You could try to use reflection or absorption spectroscopy, ie how the containers reflect or absorb light at different wavelengths, but any labeling or anything stuck to the outside of the container could throw you off.

If your containers are commercial beverage containers, reading the UPC code would be your best bet. Each product has a specific code. By reading the code, you know what the container is made of. This is how a machine a my local grocery works.

Getting back to physics, the best way to approach the problem would be to use physical properties of the different containers. Metallic containers will react to a varying electromagnetic field by producing eddy currents. These can be used to detect and sort out any metallic containers.

Glass and plastic can be sorted by using the fact the the density of plastic is much smaller than the density of glass. If you are sorting commercial beverage containers, my guess is that the smallest glass container is much heavier than the largest plastic container, and weight can be used to separate them. Alternatively, a "just right" pulse of air may be able to lift or push any plastic container while not being able to lift or push a glass container.